# How to validate that at least 1 checkbox per group was checked in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am building a page where user will be able to choose various goods from a category ( e milk/fruit...)
This is done in a form.

Then, I send them to server and do some processing.

```
<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt1"/>yogurt1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt2"/>yogurt2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt3"/>yogurt3</div>
</div>              

<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple"/>apple</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="pear"/>pear</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="melon"/>melon</div>
</div>  

....
```

**Q: How can I validate that the user has chosen at least 1 product from each category ( i.e. at list 1 milk item and at least 1 fruit item were checked)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*attribute selector*](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [*:checked*](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-selector as follow:

```
if ($(':checkbox[name="milk"]:checked').length > 0) {
    alert('Min 1 checked');
}
```

For multiple groups:

```
if ($(':checkbox[name="milk"]:checked').length == 0 || $(':checkbox[name="fruit"]:checked').length == 0 || ...) {
    alert('Please check at least one checkbox from group');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/791L71qw/)

Answer (score 2):

You should check `length` of selected values.

```js
$("#check").on("click", function() {
  if ($("[name=\"milk\"]:checked").length > 0 && $("[name=\"fruit\"]:checked").length > 0) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt1" />yogurt1</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt2" />yogurt2</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt3" />yogurt3</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" />apple</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="pear" />pear</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="melon" />melon</div>
</div>
<div id="check">check</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hard-coding every checkbox name in your validation, you could also create a more dynamic solution that will handle any name.

This process I would suggest is best explained by the comments in this snippet demo below:

```js
// execute function on dom-ready
$(function(){
    // bind an event handler to the form's 'submit' event
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
        // get all checkboxes within our form
        var $checkboxes = $('#myForm input[type="checkbox"]');

        // create an object to use as a map of checkbox names and whether or not one of them is checked
        var checkboxMap = {};

        // iterate over all checkboxes
        $checkboxes.each(function(i, el){
            // get the name of this checkbox
            var name = el.name;
            // if our checkbox map has a truthy value at the key 'name'
            // then keep that value, otherwise assign a value based on whether or not this checkbox is checked
            checkboxMap[name] = checkboxMap[name] || el.checked;
        });

        // iterate over all names in our checkbox map
        for(var name in checkboxMap){
            // if we find a name without a truthy value, that means a there was no option chosen for that checkbox
            if(!checkboxMap[name]){
                // give an error alert and stop the form from being submitted
                alert('You must choose at least one ' + name);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
    <div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt1"/>yogurt1</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt2"/>yogurt2</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="milk" value="yogurt3"/>yogurt3</div>
    </div>              

    <div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple"/>apple</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="pear"/>pear</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="melon"/>melon</div>
    </div>  

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```